# fetch data from a dynamic page/table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, sql, jquery-mobile

The dynamic page is created to display the data fetched from the database, the dynamic page also creates a table for the data to be presented in.

I then have a button (btnJoin) which is under every set of results, the button triggers a function that updates the table.

In order to update the table I need to fetch the specific event that the user joins, therefore is it possible to fetch the data from title (response.rows.item(i).Title) of the specific event the button was pressed on?

My SQL query for the update function should look something like:

```
tx.executeSql("Update soccerevents SET NoPeople  = NoPeople +1 WHERE Title = '" + response.rows.item(i).Title + "'", [], successJoin,errorCB);
```

JavaScript (Dynamic Page/Table):

```
function fetchEvent() {
   db = window.openDatabase("SoccerEarth", "2.0", "SoccerEarthDB", 2 * 1024 * 1024);
   db.transaction(function(tx) {
   var TitleT = document.getElementById("texttitle").value;
   tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM SoccerEvents WHERE Title LIKE '%" + TitleT + "%'", [], successCBValue, errorCB);
         });
 function successCBValue(tx, response, page_id) {
    var formElements = "<table id='resulttable' data-role='table' data-mode='reflow' class='ui-responsive table-stroke table-stripe'><thead><tr><th>Title</th><th>Location</th><th>NoPeople</th><th>Date</th><th>Description</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
     for (var i = 0; i < response.rows.length; i++) {
     formElements += "<tr><td>"
      + response.rows.item(i).Title + "</td><td>"
      + response.rows.item(i).Location +"</td><td>"
      + response.rows.item(i).NoPeople + "</td><td>"
      + response.rows.item(i).Date +"</td><td>"
      + response.rows.item(i).Description + "<button data-rowtitle='" + response.rows[i].Title + "' data-mini='true' class='btnJoin'>Join</a></td></tr>";
      }
    formElements+="</tbody></table>";
      alert("For better viewing of events, tilt phone landscape.");
     $('#page_body').append('<div data-role="page" data-theme="d" id="' + page_id + '"><div data-role="content">' + formElements + '<a href="#page4" data-role="button" data-mini="true">Return</a></div></div>');
     $.mobile.initializePage();
     $.mobile.changePage("#" + page_id);
        $(document).on("click", ".btnJoin", function(e){
                    var title = $(this).data("rowtitle");
                    alert(title);
                });
   }
}
 function updateEvent() {
         var title = document.getElementById("rowtitle");
         db = window.openDatabase("SoccerEarth", "2.0", "SoccerEarthDB", 2 * 1024 * 1024);
         db.transaction(function(tx) {
         tx.executeSql("Update soccerevents SET NoPeople  = NoPeople +1 WHERE Title = '" + title + "'", [], successJoin,errorCB);
              });
         function successJoin() {
         navigator.notification.alert("You have joined the event!", null, "Information", "ok");
         $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#page4" );
                                                                                 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add the title as a data attribute of the button

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.rows.length; i++) {
    formElements += "<tr><td>" + response.rows[i].Title + "</td><td>" + 
    response.rows[i].Location +"</td><td>" + 
    response.rows[i].NoPeople + "</td><td>" + 
    response.rows[i].Date +"</td><td>" + 
    response.rows[i].Description + 
    "<button data-rowtitle='" + response.rows[i].Title + "' class='btnJoin' >Click me</button></td></tr>";
}
```

Then in the button click handler, retrieve the attribute using the jQuery data() method:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnJoin", function(e){
    var title = $(this).data("rowtitle");
    alert(title);
});
```

## **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/pu6hmcux/)**

Comment: I attempted the above (didn't put in the click handler) and the dynamic page does not open at all now. I took out the + response.rows[i].Title +  and replaced it was just some dummy words, and the dynamic page started working as usual. So it looks like I can't actually use the response.rows within the button?

Comment: I have also updated my question so it shows my function (updateEvent) that attempts to get the data from title.

Comment: @Mahdi, you probably just have a typo somewhere in there. Make sure the right quotes are there. If dummy text works, inserting the title should also work...

Comment: I copied and pasted your code..? Also, when I said I used dummy text, I completely removed the ++ and double quotes so data-rowtitle='test' worked.

Comment: Ok, I removed the double quotes and just left the single quotes in there and the page is working again. However, I am confused to what variable I use for my updateEvent function. Are you able to elaborate on how I can pull the title into my updateEvent function? Appreciate  your help.

Comment: alert(title); is giving me + response.rows[i].Title + rather than the actual data, so this is because I took out the double quotes, so it's problematic now. As, when I have the double quotes and single quotes both around the item response it stops the function from running, and then when I take just the double quotes out it reads the item response as a text input. Any ideas?

Comment: @Mahdi, can you update the fiddle to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I have put my code in a jsfiddle session so it's easier for you to see how it is displayed on my js file -https://jsfiddle.net/pb6d6xva/#&togetherjs=OpBVvlvU8h

Comment: So with the current code you can see in the jsfiddle session, when I click to see the results, nothing happens, however, as soon as I make the rowtitle text without the double quotes the dynamic page is created and data is displayed.

Comment: I have also updated the code in my question above. thanks

Comment: @Mahdi: https://jsfiddle.net/pb6d6xva/2/ Try using your original format: data-rowtitle='" + response.rows.item(i).Title + "', then pass title to your updateevent

Comment: awesome stuff, the page is now loading as well the join button working. After pressing the join button when I return to the page I can see the NoPeople has gone up. However, after I join an event and then return to that page, the page kind of freezes and I can no longer scroll up/down the page. Can you see why this might be?

Comment: Think I may know the issue, I stupidly removed certain elements of  $.mobile.changePage("#" + page_id); but I cannot remember what I had within it. Are you able to inform me on what is missing from changePage that should be there as I believe that is the issue.

Comment: @Mahdi, your fiddle doesn't actually work for me, so i can't see your new issues.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have created a new fiddle with the updated javascript - https://jsfiddle.net/mpe9w8qq/1/#&togetherjs=FI19b7vi1L

Comment: So when the dynamic page opens, the page works fine, I can scroll up/down and select buttons. However, if I click a button and then return to the dynamic page I cannot move up or down the page, it is as though it is frozen in a certain position.